# ZeroDivisionError: 0.0 to a negative or complex power

Tags: python, python-2.7, divide-by-zero

I wanted to find an integral ((sin x)^8, {x,0,2*Pi}) and tried to write a simple program, without any external modules as "math", which calculate Taylor series and summarize it for interval (0,2*Pi) but an errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\ShAD\sin.py", line 27, in <module>
    sum+=(ser(i*2*3.1415926/k))**8
  File "E:\python\ShAD\sin.py", line 21, in ser
    sin_part+=((-1)**(j-1))*(a**(2j-1))/(fact(2*j-1))
ZeroDivisionError: 0.0 to a negative or complex power
```

suddenly occurs. And I just don't see where something is divided by zero or have power of complex number, all variables have only real positive value.
"k" is a value both for terms of series quantity and interval (0,2*Pi) division.

```
sum=0
k=20
res=0

def fact(t):
    if t==0 or t==1:
        res=1

    else:
        res=1
        for l in range(2,t+1):
            res=res*l           
    return res

def ser(a):
    sin_part=a
    for j in range(2,k):
        print fact(2*j-1)
        sin_part+=((-1)**(j-1))*(a**(2j-1))/(fact(2*j-1))
        print 'yay'
    return sin_part


for i in range(0,k-1):
    sum+=(ser(i*2*3.1415926/k))**8
print sum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I just don't see where something is divided by zero or have power
>   of complex number, all variables have only real positive value.

Not true.  On the first iteration of

```
for i in range(0,k-1):
    sum+=(ser(i*2*3.1415926/k))**8
```

you have `i=0`, so the argument to `ser` is 0, so `a == 0`, and you have `(a**(2j-1))`, which takes 0 to a complex power.

Maybe you meant `a**(2*j-1)`?  Python uses `j` for the unit imaginary, and so `2j-1` is a complex number.

Comment: Maybe you meant a**(2*j-1)?

So, it is!
Thank you very much, I just misspeled one expression. Fixed it and all goes fine.